Connecting an Industrial device (Linux) to the factory server network?
We have a situation where we would like to connect an Industrial Device (Linux OS) to a factory server network to backup logs and data.
Industrial Device (Linux OS) - 172.31.20.x
Factory Network - 192.168.20.x
How do we make this happen? Can a routing table be implemented on the corporate server to route 172 IP to 192 IP and have it functional?
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Why can't you change/configure the IP address of your "Industrial Device"?

@brhans we could, but there are several devices connected to the Industrial Switch, which requires them all to be changed.

If you are planning to connect the device to both networks, then it will also have 2 IP addresses. You may need to add a basic diagram of current vs what you're trying to get

So, to clarify - this is not a case of "you have this device that you want to plug into your factory network", but more a case of "you have this device already running on the corporate network and you want to expose it over in the factory network"? Are these 2 networks already connected somehow?

The machine is not connected to the outside world. The address range of 172 is only for the machine and its industrial hardware PLC, Drives, HMIs etc. The 192 is the corporate network that we would like to connect to. So a network drive path can be established for the IPC to backup data. Changing all the machine IPs to 192 is possible but risking the machine to stop if the IP is reassigned or changed at the server end.


Can a routing table be implemented on the corporate server to route 172 IP to 192 IP and have it functional?

Technically yes, but that's really more the job of a router. (The enterprise kind, not the home wifi kind.) It would be very ordinary router configuration to have an 172 interface, an 192 interface, plus anything else you need, and to forward packets between them as needed.
(and, more importantly, a router could be set up to refuse to forward what's not needed – you probably don't want whoever hacks into the server to immediately have access to the factory equipment!)
You could do it without a router, but in that case it would be better to install a new Ethernet interface on the server and configure it for the 172 subnet – that way the two networks would remain separate.
(The problem with your plan of directly connecting everything and "implementing routing tables" directly on the server – assuming the server still has just one Ethernet interface – is that it would practically result in both subnets sharing the same Ethernet broadcast domain, and while that's "not recommended" on regular networks, I get the feeling it could cause great trouble in an industrial LAN.)

You are absolutely right on the "cause trouble in an industrial LAN" bit. As I am more worried an IP change/reassignment in the server end could mean the machine will be left useless until we re-download the software with the new network setting changes.
